# Rails Pagination for Articles / Strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am aware and have regularly used Rails will_paginate. It's worked well for collections. Now, I'd like to use it to paginate a string. The application is paginating a long article. The article is a string and paginate expects a collection. I am not sure what to do. Do I covert the string into an array?

Is there a standard Rails way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A band-aid solution would be to create a separate table. For example, you could have the model `Post.has_many :pages`.

Then all you have to do it paginate through `@post.pages.order("page_number ASC")`.

Comment: I assume that one hack is to convert the string into a collection. I am not sure about creating a new model for this. It creates a lot complexity for editing. Also, what if I want to change the size of the page in the future? If I need to convert, I think it be better to do just for display purposes but not the article itself.

Comment: One way I think this that can be solved is to do: post.scan().paginate, with the right regex i think the string can be coverted into an array and then paginate can handle in a normal fashion; does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

gem 'html_slicer'

Requires Ruby 1.9.2/1.9.3 and Rails 3 or more.